# Excel with pandas - once read, pandas do not take changes made to xlsx file into account

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I need to convert an xlsx file into csv. After googling, I found this satisfying answer :

```py
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_excel("./data/myxlsxfiles.xlsx" )
read_file.to_csv("./data/mycsv.csv", index=None, header=True, sep=";")
```

This works fine. However, something surprising occurs and I could not find any suitable solution on the internet.

The above code is in a script and each time the script is called, I get a csv from the xlsx file.
Now I correct my excel file, close the excel file, erase the csv file and start again the process. And there it is ! the csv file do not take into account the changes made to the excel file. It seems that the previous version of the excel file was cached somewhere in memory and pandas is using it.
For the time being, the only workaround found is to rename the xlsx file. I don't find this very convenient.

Has one of you an idea of what's happening and how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the modified excel? Are you not saving as a different copy? Do you run the script after the excel is saved to file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to clear the read_file variable first, but I think it's a problem on Windows.

Otherwise, you can just duplicate the file into a temp folder, read the duplicate, proceed it and then delete the duplicate. Like this (not tested):

```
path = "./data/"
temp_path = "./data/temp/"
filename_orginal = path + "myxlsxfiles.xlsx"
filename_temp = temp_path + "myxlsxfiles_" + int(time.time()) + ".xlsx"

#Check if folder exists
if os.path.exists(path) == False:
    os.mkdir(temp_path)

#Copy file
shutil.copyfile(filename_orginal, filename_temp)

#Do your stuff
read_file = pd.read_excel(filename_temp)
read_file.to_csv("./data/mycsv.csv", index=None, header=True, sep=";")

#Remove temp file
os.remove(filename_temp)
```